# Javascript framework multi-page application

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

Which Javascript Framework do you recommend me to create a medium-large size **multi**-page web application?
or are JavaScript MVC Frameworks only for 'single-page' apps?

Answer (score 0):

One easy multi-page setup is through [parcel](https://createapp.dev/parcel).  Simply change the *package.json* *start script* to read

```
"start": "parcel src/*.html"
"build-prod": "parcel build src/*.html"
...
```

Answer (score -1):

I have never used a JavaScript framework but JavaScript MVC seems to have what you are looking for.

What features are you looking for in a framework?

JavaScript MVC includes jQuery, a template manager, auto unit testing, and auto documentation.

For a JavaScript app, I usually just start with a prebuilt html/css template and jQuery.

Comment: I need a way to organize my jQuery code... I thought about using a mvc framework..

Answer (score -3):

[AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) provides a great way to create single page applications. This allows for our site to feel more and more like a native mobile application since we have a single page app.

It provides typical  routing using AngularJS routing .For advanced routing we have an excellent routing module called [ui-router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site), it support nested routing and a lot.

Also provide [ngAnimate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) module which animates our page change.

Also, we can use the [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) modular script loader which improves speed and quality of the code.